# Java json object size: JsonNode vs. String

Tags: java, json, string, memory, jackson

I work on a java application that needs to hold ~50k json objects in memory.

Each json string is ~5000 characters long.

Extra memory consumption is my concern.
I want to compare the json objects later, but processing is not my concern, only extra memory consumption.

What is more efficient:

- Keep json as java String
- Keep json as Jackson `JsonNode` object

I tried serializing the JsonNode objects and the resulting files are smaller, than the string size - but I am not sure if the same is true in memory.

**My use-case:**

I need to detect changes to some objects, which are encoded as json. This change detection runs every minute and compares the current state with the last state (which we hold in memory).

There are no hooks or events or similar to get changes.

We already hold a list of these objects in memory - with only a limited subset of the json fields.

I cannot change that architecture.

Now instead of mapping json data to some Pojo and comparing each property manually, the idea is to hold the json string/objects and then calculate the diff/patch with some library.
This simplifies the logic a lot and is more generic - but we are worried about the extra memory consumption.

Comment: Your question may in fact be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask "how do I fix this code problem" when the best solution is to use a different approach entirely (such as perhaps *not* holding 50k JSON objects in memory, but instead using a database, and extracting smaller amounts of data on an as-needed basis). Consider telling us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Comment: Added my use-case. There is no code problem, this is purely research about expected memory consumption for different scenarios.

Comment: There's a little you can do with a plain `String`. Use-case incomplete. When you have two JSON-objects with no particular order of properties, in order to compare them efficiently, you would need to index these properties.

Comment: I only expect a very small subset of the json objects to actually change every minute (and I can check for a change very quickly by only comparing one version field, but then I need to get detailed change information).
But I still need to hold all objects in memory.
So I can still convert the string later to JsonNode for processing.

Comment: @HectorLector I have no idea which degree of Consistency and Availability you need, you might consider various non-SQL storage solutions like Redis, DinamoDB, etc. for caching and retrieving your data (I'm pretty sure you can find something sufficiently fast). That's the only way to how you can reduce memory consumption of your application.

Comment: Hey @HectorLector what is the status of your issue? Did you check out my answer? If my answer helped you solve your issue I would appreciate it if you marked it as correct!

Comment: We are going to test it look at the memory consumption. I was hoping someone could (from Jackson library?) could give me an answer, based on some experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the java.lang.instrument package's [getObjectSize](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#getObjectSize-java.lang.Object-)() method, to get approximations on the sizes of the objects with the both ways.

```java
long getObjectSize(Object objectToSize)
```

From the javadoc:

> Returns an implementation-specific approximation of the amount of storage consumed by the specified object. The result may include some or all of the object's overhead, and thus is useful for comparison within an implementation but not between implementations. The estimate may change during a single invocation of the JVM.